# Is it possible to use path module in browser?

Tags: node.js, webpack

Is it possible to use path module (e.g. path.parse) in the browser using Webpack?
Always getting a `parse is not a function` error. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you cant use the path module in the browser, but there is an implementation for it for browsers.

check this link, it might be useful

> https://github.com/browserify/path-browserify

Answer (score 0):

[node-stdlib-browser](https://github.com/niksy/node-stdlib-browser) is the modern solution for node polyfills

Comment: It's worth noting that `node-stdlib-browser` depends on `path-browserify`, which is the library suggested in the accepted answer and more specifically address the OP's question.